# Create RequestScope bean or fallback to singleton

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to create RequestScope bean to handle web code in a specific way, however this code can sometimes be called from non web thread and in that case I need to use standard Singleton.

Is there any good pattern to fallback during bean creation process based on the web thread availability?

The only thing that I can think of at this moment is to try to create bean with `BeanFactory.getBean` and return Singleton on `BeanCreationException`.

Comment: Have you tried to use Spring Profiles already?

Comment: I don't think that spring profiles are a good fit here. The code can be execute either from a web request context or from JMS listener, but both in the same runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution below allows to get singleton or get/create request scope bean based on the execution context.

```
interface Consumer{}
class SingletonConsumer implements Consumer{}
class WebRequestBasedConsumer implements Consumer{}


class ConsumerFactory {
    private final BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private final SingletonConsumer singletonConsumer;

    Consumer getConsumer() {
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null) {
            return beanFactory.getBean(WebRequestBasedConsumer.class);
        }
        return singletonConsumer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can define two beans of the same class but configured them with different bean names and different scopes . Then use `@Qualifer` to differentiate which bean (i.e which scoped of the bean) you want to inject.

For example ,the bean definitions look like:

```
@Bean(name="singletonFoo")
@Scope(scopeName = "singleton") //can omit it as the default scope is singleton already.
public Foo singletonFoo(){

}

@Bean(name="requestScopedFoo")
@Scope(scopeName = "request")
public Foo requestScopedFoo(){

}
```

Then to inject singleton bean :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("singletonFoo")
private Foo foo;
```

And to inject requested scoped bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("requestScopedFoo")
private Foo foo;
```